# iText embedding font fails

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a function that creates a pdf from a pdf template. The template contains 6 lines of text.

5 of the lines should be in font 'Myriad Pro'. This works fine.
The other 1 line ("name") should be in font 'TheSerif'. We purchased this font through the legit vendor. This line does not seem to work. The function does not throw an error but in the output PDF the line is unreadable.

I am using the same procedure for both fonts so I have no idea why the second one does not work.

```
  BaseFont Myriad = null;
  BaseFont TheSerif = null;

  Myriad = BaseFont.CreateFont("D:\\Drukwerk\\MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  TheSerif = BaseFont.CreateFont("D:\\Drukwerk\\TSer6C__.pfm", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("name", "textfont",TheSerif , null); 
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("Function", "textfont",Myriad, null);
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("telephone", "textfont",Myriad, null);  
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("mobile", "textfont",Myriad, null);  
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("fax", "textfont",Myriad, null);    
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("emailadres", "textfont",Myriad, null);
```

EDIT:
I Changed the Font creation to the following

```
TheSerif = BaseFont.CreateFont("D:\\Drukwerk\\TSer6C__.pfm", 
                                BaseFont.WINANSI,
                                BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 
                                true, 
                                FileToByteArray("D:\\Drukwerk\\TSer6C__.afm"), 
                                FileToByteArray("D:\\Drukwerk\\TSer6C__.pfb"));
```

This function takes the pfb and afm file as parameters. I am getting the following error now: 'not a valid .pfm file'

Answer (score 2):

PFM files are font metrics files (Printer Font Metric) for postscript fonts. This file does not contain any character drawing commands.

PFM files usually goes along with a PFB or PFA file containing the glyph drawings, this is the file you should use.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with itext but you should try to use this overload  BaseFont CreateFont(String name, String encoding, bool embedded, bool cached, byte[] ttfAfm, byte[] pfb, bool noThrow) when dealing with pfm.  You'll have to specify the pfb file data as a byte array

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this function. Do you know how to pass pfb and ttfAfm as a byte array?

Comment: I found a function to get the byte arrays. I updated my question.

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(pfbFileName)  should return a byte[] containing the pfb file data

Comment: What happens if you specify null instead of the afm byte data ? pfm and afm should carry more or less the same metrics data; i don't think you have to specify both

Comment: this does not give an error but the font is not embedded correctly. Still unreadable characters in the output PDF.

Comment: I'm a little out of options here, sorry :) Can you put a sample output PDF file on a server so I can have a look? Does the font gets embedded and it is a an encoding problem ; if so changing the encoding from WINANSI to IDENTITY_H may help?

Comment: I dont think the encoding is the problem. When I open the PDF acrobat reader shows a warning that some text might not display correcly due to a missing font. This leads me to believe the embedding fails. Unfortunatly i cannot put a PDF file because it contains personal information. The text that doesnt show properly is shown as circles. Thank you for your input so far, maybe we just need to look for another approach.